Is there a commonly accepted definition for weighted RMS difference?
Assuming there are two datasets $x$ and $y$, both containing $n$ data points: $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$, one of the most widely recognized measures of difference between the two datasets would be their RMS difference, the definition of which is simple:
$$\mathbf{RMSD}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i-y_i)^2}}$$
If some of the datapoint-pairs are known to be less important for a domain-specific reason, this can be expressed by associating each pair with a weight: $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$, where $w_i$ are positive real numbers.
It would follow that one would use a weighted RMSD as the difference metric in this case. But as far as I can tell there is no commonly accepted definition of wRMSD, and there are two plausible candidates:

RMS of weighted differences: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{[w_i(x_i-y_i)]^2}}$
Root-mean of weighted square differences: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{w_i(x_i-y_i)^2}}$

My question is, is either of these formulas commonly accepted as "weighted RMSD" or under some different name? If not, which of these formulas are more sensible to use as a difference statistic between two datasets?

Your 2 is closer to what is used though you would typically use $\frac1{\sum w_i}$ rather than $\frac1n$.  Wikipedia discusses the related topic of the weighted variance.
